# Python installation missing a lot of things on Mountain Lion

Tags: python, macos, directory, osx-lion, osx-mountain-lion

On doing 'which Python' it says '/usr/local/bin/python'. But when I go there through 'finder' there's nothing there. I can see /Library/Python through finder and on clicking Library/Python I see 2.3, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7.

The default Python currently is 2.7which I can see with --version. But all it has is /site-packages. How is this possible? I am not sure if it is the one that came with the OS or if it was installed later by someone. I am so so confused.

OSX 10.8.4

Comment: What is the reason you needed to install another Python 2.7 instead of using the one that came with your system? If you don't have a good answer to that, the easiest way to avoid all this confusion is to just get rid of that other Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have found is just a symlink to the python binary, try doing:

```
ls -l /usr/local/bin/python
```

this will show you where this simlink is pointing to. For example I get (see the end of the line):

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 yaser  admin  33 Mar 30 15:59 /usr/local/bin/python -> ../Cellar/python/2.7.3/bin/python
```

Normally it is located at:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/
```

Comment: Thanks :) This worked. Got "lrwxr-xr-x  1 name  admin  33 Aug 25 12:22 /usr/local/bin/python -> ../Cellar/python/2.7.5/bin/python

Comment: @user2480526, glad to hear! that means it was probably installed using Homebrew.

Comment: Yes - someone installed some stuff with 'brew' the other day.

Answer (score 3):

First, /usr/local/bin/python is *not* the Apple-supplied Python; that's always in /usr/bin/python.

Second, /Library/Python/X.Y is not *supposed* to have anything but site-packages. In particular, that's where you put packages that you want to be shared by all framework builds of PythonX.Y on the system. (There's also /usr/local/lib/pythonX.Y, which also has a site-packages, intended for packages that you want to be shared by all builds, framework and non-framework.)

The actual Apple-supplied Python itself is in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework.

Most third-party framework builds are in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework. However, Homebrew, MacPorts, and Fink all install to different places. For example, Homebrew will install to `/usr/local/Cellar/python/X.Y.Z/Frameworks/Python.framework.

Non-framework builds instead go into somewhere like /usr/local/share/pythonX.Y—although again, Homebrew, MacPorts, and Fink install to different places.

Finally, many installations will create symlinks (or, sometimes, wrapper scripts) to more typical places. In particular, /usr/local/bin/python is likely a symlink to Versions/X.Y/bin/python inside the appropriate Python.framework as explained above.

---

If this is all too confusing for you to even comprehend, the simplest thing to do is to uninstall the extra Python2.7 that you installed, and [just use Apple's](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/02/sticking-with-apples-python-27.html). There are certainly good reasons for some people to have another Python 2.7 around (the blog post linked above shows a number of them), but if you don't *have* such a reason, why make things harder on yourself?

Since it looks like you're using Homebrew, you can even nondestructively test whether getting it out of the way causes any problems: `brew unlink python` will remove all traces of the Homebrew Python from your normal PATH, but leave the actual files behind. Then, if you want it back, just `brew link python`; if you're happier without it, `brew uninstall python`.

It's worth noting that many common reasons for thinking you need multiple PythonX.Y installations can be solved much more easily, and cleanly, by using [`virtualenv`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv).

---

If you're using MacPorts or Fink, they're explicitly designed to try to stay out of the way of the standard system locations. So, everything will be installed somewhere under your MacPorts/Fink root, which defaults to `/opt/local` or `/sw`, respectively. (I'll assume `/opt/local`.) That means a framework build will go somewhere like `/opt/local/Library/Frameworks`, with symlinks into `/opt/local/bin` and `/opt/local/lib` and the like. The site packages will be in `/opt/local/Library/Python/X.Y` and/or `/opt/local/lib/pythonX.Y`.

So, there's no possibility of any conflict with any other Python installation… except, of course, that `/opt/local/bin` and `/usr/local/bin` are probably both on your PATH, it's still possible that `pip` means `/usr/local/bin/pip` from the Apple or Python.org installation, while `ipython` means `/opt/local/bin/ipython` from the MacPorts one…

Comment: +1 nice answer, but it will be cool if you could extend it by details where exactly MacPorts and Fink install pythonic staff. And maybe mentioning of possibility of using virtual environments will be also some hint for beginners.

Comment: @andi: Good points. Adding all of the details of where everything goes in every installation with every option would make this way too long (and way too much work for me…), but a quick description instead of just saying "different places" is definitely better. And you're right, mentioning virtual environments is a very good idea. Thanks; hopefully the edited version is better.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to following the symlink you can import a package and type the name of the package to find where it is on disk:

```
>>> import crypt
>>> crypt
<module 'crypt' from '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/crypt.so'>
```

Answer (score -1):

`/usr` and several other system paths are not visible in the Finder.

Comment: How is this an answer to the OP's question?

Comment: Thx. I need to see the contents of the Python installation. How do I do that?

Comment: OP said that "there's nothing there" and I was simply explaining that fact.

Comment: @user2480526 you might try `cd /usr/local/bin/python` and then `ls` to see what is there.

Comment: Doesn't work - " -bash: cd: /usr/local/bin/python: Not a directory " Tried python27, python2.7-same result

Comment: Sorry of course not. /usr/local/bin/python is an executable. Try `cd /usr/lib/python2.7`.

Comment: Doesn't Apple rename a number of standard Unix directories in OSX?  usr=User, etc?  I seem to recall coming across that at one point or another.

Comment: @SilasRay: No. `/usr` is `/usr`; `/Users` is just the place where user home directories go by default (like `/home`, `/users`, etc. on other *nix distros).

Comment: @SilasRay: Apple _does_ add some unique things, primarily `/Library` and friends (`/System/Library`, each `~/Library`, etc.) and `/Applications` and similar. In many cases where you'd have a single executable or .so, or a bunch of scattered files, you instead get a framework or application bundle with all the files inside it, and that goes into one of the special OS X locations. For example, Python is normally built and distributed as a framework.